# can't pass Object directly to prisma.object.create function typescript

Tags: typescript, prisma

I'm currently learning typescript and prisma. For practice I'm currently trying to rewrite an old Project that is written in js and uses a mariaDB connector with a database.js File to handle the database connection.

This is the part of my `schema.prisma` file that contains the Field model

```
enum AreaUnit {
    sqm
    hectar
    acre
    sqk
}

model Field {
    id          String   @id @default(uuid())
    name        String
    area        Int
    unit        AreaUnit
    latitude    Decimal?
    longitude   Decimal?
    description String?
    sensors     Sensor[]
}
```

In the file `Field.ts` i have a type called `FieldProps`

```
type FieldProps = {
  id?: number;
  name: string;
  area: number;
  unit: AreaUnit;
  latitude?: number;
  longitude?: number;
  description?: string;
};
```

and also a static async method create() in a class Field{}:

```
export class Field {
  static async create(field: FieldProps): Promise<Field> {
    let createdField: Field = await prisma.field.create({
      data: { field },
    });
    return createdField;
  }
}
```

The field variable has the Type FieldProps. Reading again through it, it makes sense why i can't pass it like that, because the create requires a speciall type but i don't know which. How can i find out which to use vscode shows me multiple but i can't write it there, because it somehow can't find it:
[image]

So how do I make it that i can use it typesafe?

Comment: What is the value of `field` parameter that you are passing? Do you get an error if you manually type all the values? Like passing id,name,area etc?

Comment: No I don't get an error if I pass everything manually. I found the solution one hour ago!

Answer (score 0):

So the solution i found is to also import Prisma and not only the PrismaClient:

```js
import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from "@prisma/client";
```

and now what I can do is use it like that:

```js
static async create(field: Prisma.FieldCreateInput): Promise<Field> {
    return await prisma.field.create({
      data: field,
    });
```

instead of using my own type `FieldProps` I directly use the one provided by Prisma: `Prisma.FieldCreateInput`.

I figured out Prisma creates a bunch of types for each Model

`node_modules/.prisma/client/index.d.ts`

```js
...
export type FieldCreateInput = {
    id?: string
    name: string
    area: number
    unit: AreaUnit
    latitude?: Decimal | DecimalJsLike | number | string | null
    longitude?: Decimal | DecimalJsLike | number | string | null
    description?: string | null
    sensors?: SensorCreateNestedManyWithoutFieldInput
  }

export type FieldUpdateInput = {
    id?: StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput | string
    name?: StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput | string
    area?: IntFieldUpdateOperationsInput | number
    unit?: EnumAreaUnitFieldUpdateOperationsInput | AreaUnit
    latitude?: NullableDecimalFieldUpdateOperationsInput | Decimal | DecimalJsLike | number | string | null
    longitude?: NullableDecimalFieldUpdateOperationsInput | Decimal | DecimalJsLike | number | string | null
    description?: NullableStringFieldUpdateOperationsInput | string | null
    sensors?: SensorUpdateManyWithoutFieldNestedInput
  }
...
```